A Lemma from Bloch's 1986 paper "Algebraic Cycles and Higher K-Theory"
I am trying to understand the idea and the proof behind Lemma 1.2 of Bloch's paper (link)
Here's what it states:

Let $G$ be a connected linear algebraic group acting on a quasi-projective variety $X$ over $k=\bar k$. Assume that $A,B$ are closed sub-varieties of $X$ such that $G\times A\rightarrow X$ is surjective and each fiber has same dimension. Now let $K=\bar K$ be a overfield of $k$. Assume $\exists$ a $K$-morphism $\psi: X_K\rightarrow G_K$ and an open dense set $V\subset X$ such that for every $x\in V_K$ (not necessarily closed), we have $$\operatorname{tr. deg}_k k(\varphi\circ \psi, \pi)(x)\geq \dim G$$where $\pi:X_K\rightarrow X$ and $\varphi: G_K\rightarrow G$ are the obvious morphisms. Finally assume that $$\phi:X_K\rightarrow X_K \\ x\mapsto \psi(x).x$$ is an isomorphism. Then the intersection $\phi(V\cap A)_K \cap B_K$ is proper in $X_K$.

Here's my attempt at understanding Bloch's arguments:
Considering the Cartesian diagram $\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
 C @>>> B\\
@VVV @VVV\\
 G\times A @>>> X
\end{CD}
We see that $\dim C-\dim B=\dim G +\dim A-\dim X$ and the same results hold true after base-chaning to $K$. We have to compute the dimension of $\phi(V\cap A)_K \cap B_K$ but since $\phi \left ((V\cap A)_K \cap C_K \right )=\phi(V\cap A)_K \cap B_K$, we need to show that $\dim (V\cap A)_K \cap C_K= \dim C_K +\dim A_K -\dim G_K\times_K A_K$.
After this, Bloch reduces to the case $C\cap A$ is $0$-dimensional by replacing $C$ with a hyper-plane section which I don't quite follow (I don't understand how $C\cap A$ is even defined). Also, what does the condition $\operatorname{tr. deg}_k k(\varphi\circ \psi, \pi)(x)\geq \dim G$ actually signify. Any help/insight would be greatly appreciated.
Edit: After looking at the Cartesian square, $\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
 (V\cap A)_K \cap C@>\theta>> C\\
@VVV @VVV\\
 (V\cap A)_K  @>{(\varphi\circ \psi, \pi)}>> G\times_k A
\end{CD}we see that the inequality of the transcendence degree is equivalent to the fact that for every $x\in (V\cap A)_K$ , $\dim \{(\varphi\circ \psi(x), \pi(x)) \}^-\geq \dim G$ and similarly for every $x\in (V\cap A)_K \cap C$, $\dim \{ \theta (x)\}^-\geq \dim G$. So we have a morphism between Noetherian schemes where the closure of the image of every point is bounded below by a fixed constant. Is there any dimension inequality which would help me complete ?
